# Can we use "with no" rather than "without"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I am wondering what is the difference between **with no** and **without** if I write the following sentence with "with no".

> I couldn't handle this situation **without** your help

Can I write this sentence as:

> I couldn't handle this situation **with no** (your) help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You could say either:

> I couldn't handle this situation without your help.

or:

> I couldn't handle this situation with no help.

In the second sentence, you could say "without help" or "with no help" interchangeably. "Without help" seems slightly more correct to me because "couldn't...with no" seems like a confusing number of negatives for one sentence. However I think that's just my personal preference; it is probably technically correct either way.

In the first sentence, with the article "your", you can only use "without".

Answer (score 2):

You can say "I want a hamburger with no ketchup" **or** "I want a hamburger without ketchup".

You could say "My three year old tied her shoes with no help!"

But your second sentence sounds very strange to my ears.